# Permissions to create OAuth client ID in Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth, google-oauth

I'd like to create some OAuth client IDs in the GCP but I do not have some permissions for that. I got a warning "You don't have permission to create an OAuth client"

[image]

I can simply add me to the role `roles/owner` and do it, but I'd like to have something like a minimal permission/role to create OAuth client IDs. What permissions/roles from this list should I use?

https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#service_account_roles

I tried `roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator` but it doesn't work.

Comment: You need the IAM permissions that start with `clientauthconfig.clients` and you will need to create a custom role from these permissions. https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/custom-roles-permissions-support I have not directly used these permissions. I am not sure exactly which ones you need beyond `list, create, get`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to create a custom role which has permissions `clientauthconfig.*`

Note: As per https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/custom-roles-permissions-support, these permissions are in testing phase so please try them out thorougly before putting in production.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Besides having at least the [Viewer role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#primitive_role_definitions) assigned in order to see the Google Cloud Platform project and navigate the Cloud Console the only relevant [permission](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/permissions-reference) in order to create an OAuth client should be `clientauthconfig.clients.create`. But notice that besides creating them, the user would not have the ability to delete or update them.

My suggestion would be to create a [custom role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-custom-roles) that have at least the following permissions:

```
clientauthconfig.clients.create
clientauthconfig.clients.createSecret
clientauthconfig.clients.delete
clientauthconfig.clients.get
clientauthconfig.clients.getWithSecret
clientauthconfig.clients.list
clientauthconfig.clients.listWithSecrets
clientauthconfig.clients.undelete
clientauthconfig.clients.update
```

And make sure that the users have at least the Viewer Role as well as this custom role assigned.